# awk adding on zeroes

Tags: bash, awk

I have this command to parse a log file, and show each IP address and number of times the IP address is in the log file.

```
for x in $(cat /var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log | awk '{print $1}' | uniq); do cat /var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log | awk -v q=, "/$x/ { count++ } END { print $x q count }";done
```

It works fine, except AWK is adding on zero's to the output.

e.g. output is

```
198.530.980.148,3
72.140.1990.7,29
```

instead it should be:

```
198.53.98.148,3
72.14.199.7,29
```

I.e. 198.53.98.148 is turned into 198.530.980.148 by AWK (extra zeroes), or 72.14.199.7 into 72.140.1990.7.

Any help or insight much appreciated.

Thanks
Paul

**UPDATE**

Just to mention Ed's very helpful alternate script below:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{cnt[$1]++} END{for (x in cnt) print x, cnt[x]}' /var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log
```

It's MUCH faster than mine.

I left the answer as is though, as technically my incorrect syntax was the error.

Comment: Your command line is full of useless use of pipes!

Comment: Not useless, they DO something. Not efficient, but not useless. Ed contributed a helpful response, maybe have a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't know your input file but this awk command:

```
awk -v q=, "/$x/ { count++ } END { print $x q count }"
```

is definitely not correct. You need to pass `$x` using same `-v` option you have for passing variable `q`.

Try this awk command:

```
awk -v x="$x" -v q="," '$0 ~ x { count++ } END { print x q count }'
```

Most likely all of your script can be written in one single awk command and there is no need of unnecessary `cat, awk, uniq` etc.

Comment: Thanks, that was it - my syntax was wrong. Adding -v x="$x" worked.

Answer (score 4):

Your whole command line can be reduced to just this:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{cnt[$1]++} END{for (x in cnt) print x, cnt[x]}' /var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log
```

Comment: Thanks Ed - when I try this though I am getting "fatal: attempt to use array `cnt' in a scalar context
"

Comment: Wow!! It works, but it is SO much faster than my script! Mine took about 15 mins to complete, this is instant. Thanks for sharing that, much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. General guideline - any time you write a loop in shell to process text you have the wrong approach and should ask for help.

Comment: What about something like this, surely this is OK? for x in $(cat file); do curl -I $x; done. I think I get your point though, for actual text processing it's wrong. Thanks again

Comment: Since what that loop in your comment is doing is not text processing you could make a case for a shell loop BUT most people I think would tell you it's a job for xargs instead and as written it contains a couple of bugs, including a UUOC, unquoted variables which will cause bizarre failures when your URLs contains globbing characters, etc., and the wrong loop structure, you need to use `while IFS= read -r x` instead.

Comment: Wow, OK thanks yet again. Not being smart at all, but this has been an education. UUOC...never heard that before, but I see now. Will re-visit my bash scripting so. Just to ask, how would you write that without cat?

Comment: no problem. FYI the xargs alternative to your loop would simply be `xargs -a file curl -l`. Shell is generally designed for construction of complex commands using pipes, not loops. Loops have their place at times too but they should not be your first guess at the right approach. Oh, and since you asked a loop without cat would be `while IFS= read -r x; do curl -l "$x"; done < file`

Comment: That's brilliant, really appreciate that. As I say, will definitely rethink bash and scripting to use constructs like the above (while IFS =read etc.) You can really see the speed difference too when the unnecessary looping is removed: the original awk command you posted is immeasurably faster than the looped and cat'ed effort I had.